# Arbol ALv C++, no se compila por este error

Tags: c++

estoy programando un arbol en c++ y me muestra un error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que ven en la imagen, este es codigo del cual me quiero guiar
pero no me compila por lo antes mencionado, si pueden apoyarme se los agradezco mucho
actualmente estoy compilando en dev c++ 5.11
no se porque esta madre no me deja subirlo solo asi
que ven en la imagen, este es codigo del cual me quiero guiar
pero no me compila por lo antes mencionado, si pueden apoyarme se los agradezco mucho

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

//funcion gotoxy para ubicar elementos segun coordenadas especificadas por los argumentos x e y.
void gotoxy(int x,int y){
HANDLE hcon;
hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD dwPos;
dwPos.X = x;
dwPos.Y= y;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);
}

struct nodo{
int num;
struct nodo *izq, *der;
};

typedef struct nodo *ARBOL;

ARBOL crearNodo(int x)
{
ARBOL nuevo = new(struct nodo);
nuevo->num = x;
nuevo->izq = NULL;
nuevo->der = NULL;
return nuevo;
}


void Insertar(ARBOL &arbol,int x){

if(arbol==NULL)
arbol=crearNodo(x);
if(x < arbol->num)
Insertar(arbol->izq, x);
if(x > arbol->num)
Insertar(arbol->der, x);
}
int auxX = 0;

void mostrarArbol(ARBOL miArbol, int auxY){


if(miArbol == NULL){

return;
}
auxX += 3;

mostrarArbol(miArbol -> izq,auxY+2);
gotoxy(10+auxX-auxY , 15+auxY);
cout << miArbol -> num << endl << endl;
mostrarArbol(miArbol -> der,auxY+2);
}

void menu()
{
system("cls");
system("color 02");
cout<<"ntt Arbol Binario n";
cout<<"t==========================================n";
cout<<" n";
cout<<"tt1. Insertar elemento "<<endl;
cout<<"tt2. Mostrar arbol "<<endl;
cout<<"tt0. SALIR "<<endl;
cout<<" "<<endl;
cout<<"nttINGRESE OPCION: ";
}

ARBOL arbol = NULL;
int x, op;

do
{
menu(); cin>> op;

switch(op)
{
case 1:
cout << " Ingrese un numero : ";
cin>> x;
Insertar( arbol, x);
system("pause";
break;
case 2:
auxX = 0;
mostrarArbol(arbol,0);
cout << endl << endl << endl;
system("pause";
break;
}

}while(op!=0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: los programadores no tienen por costumbre ser también adivinos o prestidigitadores, si no enseñas un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema va a estar complicado que te demos alguna respuesta

Comment: en esta madre no se como subir el codigo dejame ahora veo

Comment: Tabula el código. Si lo hubieses hecho habrías visto dos cosas: No tienes una función `main` y que tienes código que no está dentro de una función

Comment: Por favor, pásate por [El Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber como funciona el sitio; sobre todo, visita [¿ Cómo elaboro una bunea pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y lo que es un [mcve]. En resumen: **No subas todo el código**, solo lo mínimo imprescindible para poder reprodocir tu problema. Un saludo.